# copying file from hfs+ to remote samba - preserving ownership and permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, samba, inode

I've started backing up my file from my local OSX machine to remote samba filesystem. however, it seems that it doesn't copy the permission alright :

here's my mount configuration:

```
/Volumes/myvol (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by ensile)
```

and when i type `ls /Volumes/myvol/xx.txt i get :`-rwx------`and group`staff`while the original file attributes were :`-rw-r--r--`and group`wheel`

is there any chance i can copy the permissions as well ?

UPDATE:

I saw that in linux there's a solution to my problem using `chmod` with `--reference` option, but it doesn't implemented in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found one easy way to solve my problem, by making tar archive out of the files i wish to store at the remote mount location. After copying back to local and extract the files, the permission remains since it's not inside of the archive inode, but in the data part.